# For reverse with sort insertion binary in Java

Tags: java, sorting, binary, insertion-sort

I am coding a sort by binary insert. This is the code:

```
private static int[] sort(int[] a){
    int x,m,L,R;
    for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
        x = a[i];
        L = 1;
        R = i;
        while (L < R){
            m = (L + R) / 2;
            if (a[m] <= x){
                L = m + 1;
            } else {
                R = m;
            }
        }
        for (int j=i;j==R+1;j--){ //with i=5 and R=1 doesn't entry inside  
            a[j] = a[j-1];
        }
        a[R] = x;
    }
    return a;
}
```

When the execution is on the inner for with values i=5 and R=1, the execution step to a[R] = x; . I don't understand this. Any idea?

Comment: well `j==R+1` is `false` in that case, so why would you expect it to enter the loop?

Comment: It's easier to learn how it is implemented - http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/BinaryInsertion.java.html